# How do I make multiple images disappear on being clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 images in the header of a basic HTML document. All of them have class = "fruits". I want each image to disappear individually when I click on it, but I can't quite get the code right.

I've been able to get all of the images to disappear at once:

```
$(".fruits").click(function() {
     $(".fruits").hide();
});
```

I can also make an individual image disappear using just the image's id:

```
$("#apple").click(function() {
     $("#apple").hide();
});
```

I've seen solutions like this suggested:

```
$(".fruits").click(function(imgId) {
　　　　　$("#" + imgId).hide();
});
```

But that doesn't work. Am I on the right track here? How do I get the image id to pull into the function to hide the image?

Comment: Use contextual lookups.  Your first snippet is doing a global selector on fruits, regardless of the one that was just clicked.  Use `this` insted.

Comment: Why do you need JQuery for such a simple thing?

Comment: `$(this).hide()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".fruits").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
.fruits {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="fruits">Apple</div>
  <div class="fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="fruits">Banana</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with vanilla javascript (a bit more verbose, but a nice chance to learn a bit):

```
var targets = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fruits'));
targets.map(function(target) { 
    target.addEventListener('click', function(e){ e.target.style.display = "none" })
};
```